# React Native connect to MongoDB without localhost

Tags: mongodb, react-native

I'm creating an app for barbers where they can add appointments. I get data from localhost and I always change Emulator IP address to 6666. How I can connect to mongoDB directly without changing IP address and running back-end?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What emulator are you referring to and how does this relate to MongoDB? If your application needs to connect to a different MongoDB instance it should have some logic for using a different connection string. Please edit your question to include more details on what you have tried and the desired outcome.

Comment: I've connected my mongoose back-end with my rn app, I'm asking how I can connect to mongodb if I need production.

Comment: Your Mongoose backend will pass a [MongoDB connection string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) to [`mongoose.connect()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html), so you need to change that to point to the appropriate MongoDB deployment (localhost versus your production deployment). Typically you would set up your backend so the connection string is read from an environment setting rather than hardcoded. Your current question still needs editing for clarity: what is the Emulator IP you are referring to, what you have tried, and what is your desired outcome?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am changing Emulator IP to 6666 and I can see my data in my application, you can check my repo : https://github.com/amahh014/dent-backend - back-end , and front-end https://github.com/amahh014/dentalApp , I currently need to always run server to read. For fetching, I use axios.get from localhost, please check my repo and you can see